# Missing token, in client side mode please provide a secret error, how do I solve this?

Tags: node.js, npm, getstream-io

I am working on a client and I get the following error 'Missing token, in client side mode please provide a secret error'. Please view the below code:

```
var stream = require('getstream');
client = stream.connect('q3nwu4pbz222', null, '25553'); 
readonlyToken = client.feed('user', '1').getReadOnlyToken();
user1 = browserClient.feed('user', '1', readonlyToken);
user1.get({limit:1}, callbackWhenFinished);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your third line of code:

```
readonlyToken = client.feed('user', '1').getReadOnlyToken();
```

This can only be generated by the back-end code, not the JavaScript running in the browser. This is why my previous example for you was using 'client' variables called `backendClient` and `frontendClient` to help you differentiate where you needed to execute the different parts of your code.